# Previously encrypted USB drive unable to format

Tags: partitioning, format, usb-drive

I have a USB pen-drive that was given to me encrypted (with the key). After backing up its content, I decided to format it to remove the encryption using gparted. The format failed as it seems the drive was auto-mounted by the system (Xubuntu), which is strange as I believe gparted would have notified me about that... Anyway, I have tried several times with gparted and cfdisk. Specially I have removed the partitions and the partition table, recreate it again but at some point fails. I have used also a tool (USB Stick formatter), but it also fails:

[image: an error ocurred]

It fails also in Windows with some error that the drive is write protected (the drive has no write protection lock)

When I mount it it displays:

```
[19560.692021] usb 2-4.3: new high-speed USB device number 13 using ehci-pci
[19560.791035] usb 2-4.3: New USB device found, idVendor=058f, idProduct=6387
[19560.791041] usb 2-4.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[19560.791044] usb 2-4.3: Product: Mass Storage
[19560.791047] usb 2-4.3: Manufacturer: Generic
[19560.791049] usb 2-4.3: SerialNumber: 1E93F26B
[19560.791326] usb-storage 2-4.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[19560.792181] scsi14 : usb-storage 2-4.3:1.0
[19561.793820] scsi 14:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  Flash Disk       8.07 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[19561.794139] sd 14:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg3 type 0
[19561.795314] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdd] 7864320 512-byte logical blocks: (4.02 GB/3.75 GiB)
[19561.796436] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdd] Write Protect is off
[19561.796441] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdd] Mode Sense: 23 00 00 00
[19561.797556] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdd] Write cache: disabled, read cache: enabled, doesn't support DPO or FUA
[19561.818830]  sdd: sdd1
[19561.822308] sd 14:0:0:0: [sdd] Attached SCSI removable disk
```

I also did: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=512 count=1`:

`1+0 records in
1+0 records out
512 bytes (512 B) copied, 0.650634 s, 0.8 kB/s`

and tried again, but it didn't change.

As a test, I tried to wipe it, with: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdd bs=512 count=10000000`

`dd: error writing ‘/dev/sdd’: No space left on device
7864321+0 records in
7864320+0 records out
4026531840 bytes (4.0 GB) copied, 682.725 s, 5.9 MB/s`

Which is correct as the drive is 4GB and I was trying to write about 5GB.
So, it seems I can write without problems. However, when I tried again in gparted, this is shown:

[image: input output error during write]

At the console, I can see:

`/dev/sdd: unrecognised disk label
/dev/sdd: unrecognised disk label
Input/output error during write on /dev/sdd`

Somehow with cfdisk I'm able to add a partition table but when I try to remove it in gparted, this shows:

[image: can't write because it is opened read-only]

What else can I do to be able to use the USB pen-drive?

**UPDATE**

As I can "dd" the pen-drive, I decided to save an image to it:

`dd bs=4M if=ubuntu-14.04.3-server-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdd`

and it succeed. I was able to open the files in the browser. However it keeps saying that it is opening it in "read-only" mode:

`mount: block device /dev/sdd is write-protected, mounting read-only`